# Insert Image on Worksheet's Header/Footer using OpenPyXL

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I'm creating a small app in `Django` that produces a `Excel` report using `openpyxl` library. Got stuck while trying to insert an image in the `header / footer` section.  The documentation [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/print_settings.html#headers-and-footers) roughly talks about inserting text (& ampersand codes). Checked the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/0f18480163b8a54843da86a505e1242bf5233245/openpyxl/worksheet/header_footer.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), but no help there either.

I see [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_headers_footers.html) has this option. Would appreciate if someone could shed me light on how to pass image's name/path in `openxlpy` or do I need to switch the library?

**View.py**

```
def get(self, request):
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    # header & footer
    ws.header_footer.center_header.text = '&G'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible in openpyxl, and unlikely ever to be so unless someone else contributes the code. Therefore, you may have to switch to using xlsxwriter.

NB. adding it would also involve preserving images from existing files, which is one of the things that makes this so challenging. We open to add general support for reading images in openpyxl 2.5

Answer (score 0):

In `openpyxl` you can add an image (inserted into `some_cell`) to a worksheet by doing the following:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_worksheet() #or wb.active
your_image = openpyxl.drawing.Image(path_to_image)
your_image.anchor(ws.cell(some_cell))
ws.add_image(your_image)
wb.save(your_filename.xlsx)
```

Comment: But how do we add the image in header/footer?

Comment: I need a hero ! Someone ready to do this feature for free ! Is gonna be loved, is gonna be proud about how he helped out ! I need a herooooooooo !!!!!!! Nah, seriously, I'm stuck as hell between openpyxl which does not do that and xlsxwriter which does not load existing file....... HELLLLPPPPP