# Is there a way to insert an image in excel header using openpyxl (Python)?

Tags: python, excel, image, header, openpyxl

I've managed to insert texts into the left and center header in excel with openpyxl. But I can't seem to find any documentation on how to insert an image into this header using openpyxl. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I did not want to change to another module since I have wayyy too much code to rewrite.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possibly not, see this previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413768/insert-image-on-worksheets-header-footer-using-openpyxl. Its old (2016) but CC says its not on the agenda, however he may comment if anything has changed regarding this feature request.